# Javascript - Label selector

Tags: javascript, html

Below is an html and Js code that has a list of devices with name and label. I have a drop down menu which is populated with names and an event listener which returns the associated label.

What could be the possible issue?

I am new to javascript and html coding. Apologies if it is a noob question.

```js
const deviceListArray = [
    { createdTime: 1691728083163, name: 'name1', label: 'label 1' },
    { createdTime: 1691725209793, name: 'name2', label: 'label 2' },
    { createdTime: 1691710614954, name: 'name3', label: 'label 3' }
];

const labelSelector = document.getElementById('labelSelector');

// Populate the drop-down menu with all the labels/names
deviceListArray.forEach(entry => {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = entry.label;
    option.text = entry.label;
    labelSelector.add(option);
});

// Event listener for when a label is selected
labelSelector.addEventListener('change', handleLabelSelection);
let selectedDeviceID;
let deviceIDSelected;
function handleLabelSelection(event) {
    const selectedLabel = event.target.value;
    const selectedDevice = deviceListArray.find(entry => entry.label === selectedLabel);
    if (selectedDevice) {
        selectedDeviceID = selectedDevice.name; // Corrected property name to 'name'
    } else {
        console.log('Device not found for the selected label');
    }
    // Call a function to perform actions with the updated selectedDeviceID
    performActionsWithDeviceID(selectedDeviceID);
}

// Function to perform actions with the updated selectedDeviceID
function performActionsWithDeviceID(deviceID) {
    deviceIDSelected = deviceID;
}

console.log(deviceIDSelected);
```

```html
<label for="labelSelector">Select Device:</label>
<select id="labelSelector">
    <option value="">Select device</option>
</select>
```

Issue is I am unable to log the associated label outside of the function although I have declared it globally.

Comment: Question needs edits. needs to be more precise about the issue. 

Are you facing issue with `console.log(deviceIDSelected);` ?

I can see that line is not inside any functions and you not calling it while the label changes. So, it will print the undefined as the initial value of the `deviceIDSelected` will be undefined till you are selecting any device from the dropdown.

Comment: I am facing issue with console.log(deviceIDSelected). Basically I need this deviceID to perform an API call in the next steps. If undefined I have other functions.. but even if the user selects a different name, the deviceIDSelected is undefined always.

Comment: The device ID will be undefined as your code.

Comment: If you want to call an api, call that inside `if (selectedDevice)`

Comment: just move ur console.log(deviceIDSelected); inside performActionsWithDeviceID methode

Comment: You haven't executed any function just defined them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like, The `console.log(deviceIDSelected)` statement is executed immediately after the script is loaded and before any interaction (like selecting a device from the dropdown) can occur. This means deviceIDSelected has not yet been updated by `performActionsWithDeviceID` and still holds its initial value (which is undefined if not explicitly initialized).

To fix this issue, you need to ensure that `console.log(deviceIDSelected)` is called after the `deviceIDSelected` variable has been updated.

Here is an example code, update `performActionsWithDeviceID` function:

```js
function performActionsWithDeviceID(deviceID) {
  deviceIDSelected = deviceID;
  logDeviceID();
}

function logDeviceID() {
  console.log(deviceIDSelected);
}
```